# MySQL Connector/Net with SSL from WCF Service fails

Tags: mysql, wcf, ssl

I'm trying to achieve the following with no success so far:
Certificate based SSL connection to an external MySQL database (v5.0) from my WCF service (hostet in IIS 7.5 on Server 2008 R2) using Connector/Net.

The guys that host the mysql db have sent me three .pem files, which I combined to a single .pfx using OpenSSL, as described in [Using SSL with MySQL Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-tutorials-ssl.html).

But when I tried to connect using the file-based approach, I got an exception that told me that mysql 5.0 doesn't support file-based mode.

So I was left with but one option: store-based certificate.
Therefore I installed the certificate on the server (hosting my wcf service) for "Local Computer", adding it to "Personal Certificates". Then after adjusting the connection string to contain

```
"SSL Mode=Required;Certificate Store Location=LocalMachine;"
```

I tested again, with some weired authentication/credential errors.

After google'ing some more, I found that there might be a problem with insufficient access rights to the certificate. So I followed the steps explained [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/901183/en-us), and used the tool WinHttpCertCfg to grant access for the account "NetworkService", which I believe is used for hosting my service.

Unfortunately I still get the following exception:

```
Message: Out of sync with server
Source: MySql.Data
Type: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
StackTrace:
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadOk(Boolean read)
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.AuthenticateNew(Boolean reset)
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate(Boolean reset)
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   bei System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   bei System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   bei System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   bei AtlasService.AtlasService.getChildNodes(UInt32 nid, Language lang, Boolean withEmpty, DateFormats format)
```

Does anyone know what the problem is here, or what I'm doing wrong?
Any help would be greatly apreciated.
Thanks in advance

/EDIT: I should add that I successfully tested the ssl connection using mysql commandline tool and workbench (with the separate .pem files)

Answer (score 0):

Ok after hours of frustration I found a solution.
It seems that there is a problem with the latest version (v6.4.3) of the connector/net lib or the combination of ssl with the versions of connector/net lib and mysql server in use.

After downgrading the connector/net lib to v6.3.7 everything works fine.